# Making a node.js service using NSSM

Tags: node.js, cmd, window, nssm

I want to create a nodejs service, so that the node server starts as my computer starts, and i do not have to keep the command prompt open all the time. I m tryng to achieve this by using NSSM.

Here is the command to create the service:

```
nssm.exe install jewel-server C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe D:\jewel\server.js
```

Run service:

```
net start jewel-server
```

But this doesnt work and give this error:

```
The jewel-server service is starting.
The jewel-server service could not be started.

A service specific error occured: 3.
```

I checked error code 3 means the path is not correct but the is path correct.
Can you tell what i am doing wrong, or is there any other open source & more reliable alternative to NSSM

Version:

```
NSSM
version: 2.24
Windows-7 64bit
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way parameters were passed was not correct, So used the NSSM GUI to set the parametes:

```
Open GUI: nssm.exe install jewel-server
```

Once the GUI is open give in the following values.

```
Path: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Arguments: D:\jewel\server.js
Press Install service
```

Done!
You can start the service now.

Answer (score 8):

According to http://nssm.cc/commands
You may want to try the following commands.

```
nssm install jewel-server "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
nssm set jewel-server AppDirectory "D:\jewel"
nssm set jewel-server AppParameters server.js
nssm start jewel-server
```

You may check the nssm by

```
nssm edit jewel-server 
nssm status jewel-server
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Above solution works fine if you want the program to be run as `node server.js` . However , if it needs to run as `npm start`  then suggestion is to create a .bat file that includes `npm start` in it and make the location of this .bat file the path to use in NSSM

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the space in the "Program Files".
All you have to do is put it in quotes like so:

nssm.exe install jewel-server "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" D:\jewel\server.js